# Doing something to take the regret away or reduce it

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Is there a phrase or idiom in English to mean that you are engaging in something to make yourself not feel as bad about having done or not done something?

Comment: There are three main possibilities here. You might do something to ***make up for*** the bad thing you did (***redeem*** yourself), or you might ***rationalise, justify*** what you did (so it's no longer "bad"), OR you might just do something completely different to take your mind off the guilt. Are you looking to describe one of those responses? Or something else?

Comment: You are *working to assuage your guilt*?

Comment: I didn't go to a get-together I was invited to. When the pictures of the dinner table were posted to telegram right before eating, I wanted to comment that I many have been missing out, but at the same time, if I had gone, I would've probably left the dinner table hungry because the food looked not enough.